# Can I set classname to change after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue.js to set data boolean to change after a few seconds with setTimeout, but the result shows that the data remain same. If I have already returned the data value, what's causing this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showMsg: false,
  },
  methods: {
    activeMsg() {
      this.showMsg = true
      this.msgNone
    }
  },
  computed: {
    msgNone() {
      const msgCounter = setTimeout(()=>{
        clearTimeout(msgCounter)
        return this.showMsg = false
      },2500)
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="activeMsg">click me</button>
  <p v-if="showMsg">hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in `activeMsg()` you should have `this.msgNone()` to actually *call* the other method.

Comment: It's a mistake to do side effects in a computed, this shouldn't be done unless you know what you're doing. Depending on how exactly you want it to work, either activeMsg method or showMsg property change should be debounced (same thing in this code but may vary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

computed property doesn't do asynchronous calls, Just called the setTimeout inside the method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showMsg: false,
  },
  methods: {
    activeMsg() {
      this.showMsg = true
      const msgCounter = setTimeout(() => {

        this.showMsg = false
        clearTimeout(msgCounter)
      }, 2500)
    }
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="activeMsg">click me</button>
  <p v-if="showMsg">hello</p>
</div>
```